# RecyclerView inside PagerAdapter not updating content

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have searched and tried a lot to get this to work, but I just cannot get it working...

I have a `PagerAdapter` fragment. Each page has a `RecyclerView` with a list of views.
When i click on one of the items in the `RecyclerView`, an `ImageView` should be shown/hidden (A star will show - Favorite).

Everything is working but ONLY if i click on one of the items, leave the fragment and then enter the `PagerAdapter` fragment again.

Here is my `PagerAdapter` code:

```
private ArrayList<List<String[]>> schedule;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArtistAdapter adapter;

//Fill schedule with information in constructor
...

    @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.schema_page, container, false);

    adapter = new ArtistAdapter(context, getData(backgrounds, schedule.get(position)));

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.artist_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, recyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int itemPosition) {
                    toggleFavorite(itemPosition, position);
                }

            })
    );

    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

private void toggleFavorite(int itemPosition, int day){
    String[] artist = schedule.get(day).get(itemPosition);

    if (artist[5].equals("false")){ 
        artist[5] = "true";
    } else {
        artist[5] = "false"; //Yes, I need it this way.
    }

    adapter.swap(getData(backgrounds, schedule.get(day), star));

    //Do other things that have to be done in the PagerAdapter

}
```

My adapter code:

```
class ArtistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistAdapter.ArtistViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ArtistRow> data = Collections.emptyList();

    ArtistAdapter (Context context, List<ArtistRow> data){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ArtistViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist_row, parent, false);
        return new ArtistViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArtistViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ArtistRow current = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(current.name.toUpperCase());
        holder.type.setText(current.type.toUpperCase());
        holder.time.setText(current.time.toUpperCase());
        holder.place.setText(current.place.toUpperCase());
        holder.background.setImageBitmap(current.background);
        holder.star.setImageBitmap(current.star);

        if (current.starShow.equals("true")){
            holder.star.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.star.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public void swap(List<ArtistRow> artists){
        data.clear();
        data.addAll(artists);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class ArtistViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView background;
        ImageView star;
        TextView name;
        TextView type;
        TextView time;
        TextView place;

        ArtistViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
            type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_type);
            time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_time);
            place = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_place);
            background= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_bg);
            star = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.star);

        }
    }

}
```

I believe that something is fishy with the adapter. 
`instantiateItem` is called a second time, when preloading the second page. So I swap out the SECOND page with the content of the FIRST page instead of replacing the first page, since it swaps out the LAST instantiated item.

When I click on an item on the first page then swipe to the next one, the next one is a copy of the fist page (but with a star on the item I clicked, which is how I want the FIRST page to be like) and not showing the second page.

So, if I scroll around the pages and the last `instantiateItem` page is the one I'm currently looking at, the swap is working flawlessly.

Anyway, how do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of taking a boolean in the ViewHolder , take one in Your Model and toggle it. See if that works

Comment: @vikramthakur Hello! I'm not sure what you mean by "Your Model". I can remove the check inside the "ArtistViewHolder", that code didn't do anything anyway. (I'll update the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I solved this issue!

Instead of overwriting the adapter in the `instantiateItem` method, I created an array with adapters like this:

```
private ArtistAdapter[] adapters;

// Instantiate the array in my constructor

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    ...
    adapters[position] = new ArtistAdapter(context, getData(backgrounds, schedule.get(position)));
    ...
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapters[position]);
}
```

And for the swap:

```
adapters[day].swap(getData(backgrounds, schedule.get(day), star));
```

I also think that it might be an idea to add this as well:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ...
    adapters[position] = null;
}
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong or have missed anything!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerview.scrollToPosition(position);
```

or create method in your adapter like this

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Quote> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList.clear();
    this.arrayList.addAll(arrayList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and use in your activity fragment

adapter.setData(arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure and I haven't tested your code but I have faced the same thing before.

Can you try this in your adapter constructor

```
private List<ArtistRow> data;
ArtistAdapter (Context context, List<ArtistRow> data){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = new ArrayList<>();
this.data.addAll(data);
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comment. This solution did not change anything, sadly :(

Comment: are you sure that it is running this line  @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int itemPosition) {
                    toggleFavorite(itemPosition, position);
                } 

whenever you click/tap something from the view?

Comment: Yes, but there are two items in the adapter, the first and the second (preloaded and therefore the last instantiated page) page/list/day in the PagerAdapter. So when I press anything in the view, it always swaps the pressed days list with the last instantiated days list.